# Board to Wire Connector Type used between Small Display and Main PCB

Tags: pcb-design, connector, spi, layout

I'm in the process of designing a PCB/Prototype and looking at different types of board-to-wire type connectors. In particular, I want to connect an SPI OLED display to the main PCB. It needs to be removable and small, but not too small that it's delicate/fragile. It also needs to be a low-profile connector since the display and PCB are packaged closed to each other.

Here's the underside of the housing. The main PCB will be within the housing just beneath the display:

[image]

Is there another name or trade-name for these type of parts that I should be searching for?

Should I look at standard .1" header pitch for connectors or is there a smaller, yet still common pitch that is still robust and inexpensive?

Also, is this the correct way to connect the  display to the pcb for this application?

update: I looking for low profile type connector like this(not not as small and with 7 connectors:
[image: Low Profile Connector]
[image]

Comment: What level of robustness are you aiming for? most people would likely just use a vanilla flat flex

Comment: @PlasmaHH It will be under some intermittent vibration. It does not need to comply with any waterproof/dusproof standards either. Flat Flex looks nice! I think that's on the right track. I would need a vertical surface mount connector(similar to the connector on the display in photo) since the PCB edges are not exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Without a measurement scale in the photo, those are probably intended to mate with .025 " (0.63 mm) square posts on a 0.1" pitch. Back in the day wire wrap pins would have been the term. The easiest way to buy them nowadays is as a [breakaway, single row male header](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv512=16&pv28=1932&pv89=1&pv90=1&pv69=80&pv589=25&FV=fff40016%2Cfff802f3%2C7004d3%2C700787%2C70078c&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)[image] in a convenient length. I've used digikey.com as the source just because the link was available, but any electronics part house should have what you need. A header using a smaller pitch will have a smaller pin, so don't try it unless you are willing to replace the female components.

Comment: I don't want to use those because they are too tall when the prototype is assembled.

Comment: @GisMofx - Then you'll need to replace the female connectors you show.

Comment: absolutely! Those are going to get cut-off once I find the correct connector

Answer (score 0):

JST [XH](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=277) or [PH](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199) are my usual gotos for something more reliable than a basic "dupont" crimp housing. You lose the ability to have a variable-size connector, but you gain incredible robustness in the connection.